# QA Access to QA is Being Denied

Tags: qa-role, testing-environment

My QA team is being denied access to the QA environment. Yes, really.

Is there a precedent for this? A good reason? Is it as monumentally stoopid as I think it is?

Are there any resources or studies which show this to be a standard in the industry?

So far, my searches haven't turned up anything, because you know, the environment is NAMED for the team that uses it, so it goes without saying. That's my theory anyway. Still, I hope someone might have something I can provide or point to in making the case for access.

Comment: Then how does the team test? What are they doing throughout the day?

Comment: Denied access to the environment, or the ability to log into the servers?  Is it that you're being denied user access or administrator access?

Comment: @Lyndon We're being denied access - as in, cannot log in to environment or servers. No user access.

Comment: @FDM right now, the actual project hasn't started. So we're all working on other things. In the meantime, they're refusing to grant access. They're also planning to remove access from a different QA team.

Comment: What is your role in the project? Was any explanation given to you why not? Who has access and for what reason? Who will do QA if you cannot?

Comment: @PeterMasiar I'm the BA. No explanation that I'm privvy to, but I've been told it's a new CTO who doesn't like QA being under Ops.

Comment: ah, good point on the ops thing.  Do the QA's also have production access to systems?

Comment: @LyndonVrooman LOL, nope! They're taking away all access. I don't understand how they can expect us to actually, yanno, DO ANYTHING.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is looking for an opinion about whether something is "stoopid".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about workplace politics: look up http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PeterMasiar It's not about workplace politics, it's about are there any resources that specifically state what the access requirements for QA should be. If there aren't any, that's fine - say so, and I'll mark it as answered. My opinion is it's "stoopid", but that's not the question.

Comment: @user246 Ditto.

Comment: @graidan If you like we can [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) about this.  I've had a similar workplace experience.

Comment: We can't really answer this question here without knowing a lot more about your group, its responsibilities, what they are supposed to be testing, how they are testing, what the product is, etc, etc.

Comment: If you have a list of things that you are responsible for and the access prevents any of them it really isn't your problem to fix, it's your responsibility to explain it to management in terms they can understand.

Comment: The 'case' for access is doing your job.  If your job responsibilities aren't documented that that's the first thing you need to do - sit down with your management and agree on the job responsibilities.  They you can talk about what you will need to do in order to do your job.  one example:  access the QA server to test x.

Comment: @graidan: yes it **is** about politics. Rules of game changed with new management, and you need to find out what they are, and how QA worked in company where CTO worked before. Maybe not politics but the rules for sure - and we here how no idea how your new CTO wants to run his or her new company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'case' for access is doing your job. If your job responsibilities aren't documented that that's the first thing you need to do - sit down with your management and agree on the job responsibilities. They you can talk about what you will need to do in order to do your job. one example: access the QA server to test x.

However we can't really answer this question, as posed here, without knowing a lot more about your group, its responsibilities, what they are supposed to be testing, how they are testing, what the product is, etc, etc.

If you have a list of things that you are responsible for and the access prevents any of them it really isn't your problem *to fix*, it's your responsibility to explain it to management in terms they can understand so they can fix the access for you.

Do all of this calmly and with smiles.  Apologize if you can't test due to access.  Tell them you feel genuinely bad you can't do your job.  Avoid anger, sarcasm, etc, etc. as it will only hurt you in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about communication. Find out what your new responsibilities are under new management, and how to gain the access you will need to fulfill these responsibilities. Possibly there are many good posts about navigating office politics on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Ie on my job they removed my access from linux box to Windows desktop where I run browser for selenium test. It was pain, but found out how to set up PuTTY session from desktop to linux box which allowed reverse tunnel from linux back to desktop. It was easier that to argue with our corporate Mordacs (Dilbert cartoon has a character Mordac - The preventer of information services)

http://computerguys.sg/2014/04/do-you-have-a-mordac-in-your-it-department/

Good luck!

Comment: That's not the problem though. Rather, not the question. I'm not asking about navigating politics, though that's what motivated it. I'm looking for studies, resources, websites, etc. that state explicitly that there are standard accesses needed for QA to function.

Comment: Also, I can't post to workplace, or rather, I can, but they don't have the tags I need. I can't find any that seem relevant, anyway. And they are outright DENYING access. It's not that I can do something to get access, and I just need to figure it out. It's that they are saying no, absolutely not, and I need to make a case for why that's not good. Resources, studies, etc. Proof that this is really how it should be.

Comment: We have no way to guess what motivated changes in rules your new CTO wants to implement. But CTO does know. Explain your role and tasks and ask how you will be performing them under new rules. it might not be stoopid just different.